# Two separate file server available with one address

Tags: file, dns, cdn, round-robin, fileserver

I have two separate file servers with different files inside.

For example:

**Server 1:**

- `file1.mp4`
- `file2.mp4`

**Server 2.**

- `file3.mp4`
- `file4.mp4`

What would be the easiest way to access the files with the same domain?

For example:

- `https://example.com/file1.mp4`
- `https://example.com/file2.mp4`
- `https://example.com/file3.mp4`
- `https://example.com/file4.mp4`

Comment: It kind of depends on the logic between a given server and the files it hosts. It is arbitrary/random or is there some deterministic logic (like all even number on one server, all odd ones on another)? If nothing deterministic you will need to maintain some mapping, and you can use either redirections or proxying on the central server. Or mounting at the filesystem level all remote files locally  to the central server, but this all depends on your global architecture. Your question is hence too vague, and a little offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Thanks. The servers are only connected via the internet no local connections. How could I get redirections working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using [nginx](http://nginx.org/) you could use this config on each of your servers, for example for `server1`:

```
upstream failover{
    server server2:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /tmp/test;

    location ~* \.(mp4)$ {
        try_files $uri @failover;
    }

    location @failover {
        proxy_pass http://failover;
    }
}
```

In this example, for files ending in `.mp4` if not found in the server they will use the [@failover location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), the one is going then to proxy the request to `server` via an [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

For `server2` you do the same but just change the address in the upstream, for example:

```
upstream failover {
    server server1:8080
}
```

In any case, if the file `.mp4` is not found in either of the servers you still getting a `404` HTTP status code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think redirections would use less bandwidth then proxying. Is that correct?

Comment: @Volvictrinker redirecting will imply a 301/302 but yes, will save less bandwidth between your servers.